# JSF: a4j:poll and performance loss

Tags: java, performance, jsf, jboss, richfaces

I have an application which displays several grids of data (on the same screen) build upon JSF 2.0 and EJB, run on JBoss 7.1.
Each grid is refreshed every 2.5 seconds using `<a4j:poll>` tag from RichFaces 4.2. After page loads everything works fine. However, after several minutes performace of the application decreases drastically. I mean the application reacts slower and slower to actions, which trigger JSF ajax request to the server. This happens no matter the browser (however, in Chrome it chokes later than in others). I wonder where the problem might lie: in the browser, in the JSF implementation or in the application itself?

Comment: It seems there is some memory leak being caused by this poll action, I would suggest monitor the objects being created using VisualVM or some  other tool

Comment: It would be good to show some of your managed bean code and your JSF code (please don't post a code wall, provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Also, make sure you don't have any business logic in your getter/setter methods and your managed beans have the right scope.

Comment: @Nambari usually these problems are caused for an abuse of the JSF framework, I don't think that a profiler could give you a hand on this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I agree with your statement "abuse of the JSF Framework" (Which I did while learning JSF). Profiler does showup these objects (I had first hand experience with it, trust me)

Comment: Have you measured a performance decrease on the server side by monitoring the method called by the poll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the reason for such behaviour. It was caused by JSF's AJAX request queue. The poll requests were processed long enough to overlap other polls next requests. As a result pending AJAX reqests were stacked in the queue and therefore blocked next requests - and so on. I solved this problem with using one massive request to refresh everything that needs to be refreshed.

Anyway - thanks for suggestions and your time.